# Monitoring external process: Exit when STDOUT matches pattern

Tags: perl, io, perl-io

I'm running a system command and waiting for output matching a specific pattern, e.g:

```
open(my $fh, '-|', 'echo line 1; sleep 20; echo line 2');
while (<$fh>) {
    print && last if /1/;
}
close $fh;
```

This will print `line 1` and leave the loop but won't exit until the external command has completed.

How can I allow the script to exit immediately after matching the required output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send `TERM` signal to the PID and then close file handle without waiting,

```
my $pid = open(my $fh, '-|', 'echo line 1;sleep 5; echo line 2') or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
    print && last if /1/;
}
kill TERM => $pid;
close $fh;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk`:

```
echo hello; sleep 2; echo pattern |awk '{print}/pattern/{exit}'
```

This will give you all the lines till pattern occurs, then exit.

Answer (score -1):

If the process is to be left running after the match is found, append an `&` to the command to run it in the background:

```
open(my $fh, '-|', 'echo line 1 && sleep 20 && echo line 2 &');
while (<$fh>) {
    print && last if /1/;
}
close $fh;
```